# Send and Receive sms through Java in RingCentral

Tags: ringcentral

I am quite new to the ***ringcentral*** APIs and currently going through all of them.

Currently going through the following reference: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/SMS/createSMSMessage

Through Java we can use an API to send SMS, but can we receive a SMS using Java.

Can someone help me in getting the *documentation/article* or any kind of *reference* where I can get to know the simple way to send and receive the SMS using Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample send SMS example with Java as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.ringcentral.*;
import com.ringcentral.definitions.*;

public class Send_SMS {
    String RECIPIENT_NUMBER = "<ENTER PHONE NUMBER>";
    String RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTID = "<ENTER CLIENT ID>";
    String RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTSECRET = "<ENTER CLIENT SECRET>";

    String RINGCENTRAL_USERNAME = "<YOUR ACCOUNT PHONE NUMBER>";
    String RINGCENTRAL_PASSWORD = "<YOUR ACCOUNT PASSWORD>";
    String RINGCENTRAL_EXTENSION = "<YOUR EXTENSION, PROBABLY ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      var obj = new Send_SMS();
            try {
          obj.sendSms();
            } catch (RestException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void sendSms() throws RestException, IOException{
      RestClient rc = new RestClient(RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTID, RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTSECRET, RINGCENTRAL_SERVER);
      rc.authorize(RINGCENTRAL_USERNAME, RINGCENTRAL_EXTENSION, RINGCENTRAL_PASSWORD);

      CreateSMSMessage postParameters = new CreateSMSMessage();
      postParameters.from = new MessageStoreCallerInfoRequest().phoneNumber(RINGCENTRAL_USERNAME);
      postParameters.to = new MessageStoreCallerInfoRequest[]{new MessageStoreCallerInfoRequest().phoneNumber(RECIPIENT_NUMBER)};
      postParameters.text = "Hello World from Java";

      var response = rc.restapi().account().extension().sms().post(postParameters);
      System.out.println("SMS sent. Message status: " + response.messageStatus);
    }
}
```

You can download the java ***SDK*** from here: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-java
and start with documentation here: https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/messaging/quick-start/java
Once you get the **library** in your application, you can start compiling it and running it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SMS Java quickstart guide: https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/sms/quick-start/java

Hope this helps!

Comment: could you explain little more about this guide you provided?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official RingCentral Java SDK: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-java, it is currently 1.0.0-beta9. We are going to release a stable version this month.

Here is a list of all the API calls that you can invoke: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-java/blob/master/samples.md, including sms sending: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-java/blob/master/samples.md#create-smsmms-message

For sms receiving, you can use our subscription and notification feature: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-java#pubnub-subscriptions--notificatioins
So whenever there is new sms, you will be notified, then you can issue api call to get the message.

For technical details, you can always send email to devsupport@ringcentral.com